# What is unhandled excpetion error mean?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am writing in Visual Studio,a C programm and I get this error: Unhandled exception at 0x77dd3e14 in SciComput.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xff630018.

Can someone explain to a quite absolute beginner what does this mean?

Comment: In short, it means that your program crashed. You should build a debug version of your program, and run in a debugger. It will stop when the crash happens, and let you examine and walk up the function call stack, and also let you examine variables and their values.

Comment: Memory used by program has a limit. The program "SciCompute.exe" is trying to access memory outside of it's limits. Hence the "Access violation reading (memory) location 0xff630018."

Comment: Can mean a lot of things ... such as your application somewhere threw an exception (such as divide by zero, or tried to read a file without checking if it's there or not) ... or a specific "throw" (if it's C++) or writing to a piece of memory not owned by you, dereferencing a NULL pointer ... and million of other reasons...

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg Is there a way of doing that debug work in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, VS is known for having a very good debugger. I'm sure you can easily find the option to run in the debugger in one of the menus (don't have VS available at the moment, so don't know which one).

Comment: Oh i get you! One final question, is there any other decent application, like Visual Studio, to use for software projects?

Comment: @IosifLazaridis: Questions asking for recommendations of tools are off topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you are trying to access a segment of memory that doesn't "belong" to your program, i.e. memory you haven't allocated, reserved.

Usually, causes for such errors are attempting to **write read-only memory** or **dereferencing NULL-pointers**.

"Unhandled exception" means that you haven't provided a way for the program to handle errors when they occur, so it simply crashes.

*Note*: You can handle exceptions via **try...catch** mechanism in C++. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dekhbbc.aspx C, however, doesn't support this.

Comment: This was very helpful. But i am only writing in C. Is there a way to allocate the "correct" memory? I mean not read-only and such?

Comment: The C++ `try catch` only work with C++ exceptions by `throw`, not with program crashes like this.

Comment: Yes there is (e.g. `malloc`) but your problem is not necessarily related to that.

Comment: Actually I am using malloc to allocate memory but, well, I can't choose the "correct" memory to allocate.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the good answer by Eutherpy, I would add that the access violation is usually from trying to read or write NULL, which is location zero. Location 0xff630018 is definitely out of bounds, but also is definitely not zero; something strange is going on here.

Windows reserves the bottom 2GB of virtual address space for the "user" half of your process -- that is, the code *you* are actually running in the process. The top 2GB, which have addresses from 0x80000000 to 0xffffffff are reserved for the use of the operating system to store data associated with your process. Any attempt to access OS-owned memory from user code will immediately result in an access violation.  But **why is your program trying to access operating system memory in the first place?**

Like I said, something strange is going on here. Likely there is some *other* memory corruption that is then manifesting in this behaviour; this is likely a symptom of some completely different bug.

These are hard to track down. Good luck!